# what does it mean by "I would have you memorized by now"

Tags: expressions, lyrics

The question's about lyrics in "Still Fallin" sung by Hunter Hayes.

The first line of the song is

> You'd think for all the days I've known you (that) I would have you memorized by now.

The reason why I put parentheses on 'that' is although the lyrics says it has 'that' in it, I don't find it grammatically correct. Am I right? or wrong?

Plus, I've been wondering what does it mean by

> I would have you memorized by now.

Does it have the same meaning as "I would have memorized every details about you."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Think" and the phrasal variation "think that" are more or less synonymous and can often be used interchangeably.  Example:

> On meeting her you'd **think (that)** she is a nice person, but she's actually a wonderful person.

It may be easier to understand if you simplify the lyric:

> You'd think (that) I would have you memorized by now

As for what it means: well, personally, it doesn't feel like a particularly clever turn of phrase. I think (that) your guess is as good as mine what the songwriter means by "memorize".  Most likely "commit to memory every detail of you", as it doesn't feel like there's any kind of deeper meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd like to add one more question. Does 'for' in the line (; You'd think for all the days I've known you that I would have you memorized by now) mean 'during'? So the 'for all the days' means 'during the entire time'?

Comment: @Jin  No, it does not mean "during".  It means something more like "because of", or "as a result of".

Comment: Oh thanks, I finally got the point. I've not encountered 'for' as a 'because of' or 'as a result of' before. Is this common in colloquial expression?

Comment: @Jin  No, I wouldn't say it's colloquial.  It's a little *stylized* and *literary*, perhaps, but not unusual.